# Where to check Microsoft Office version from product number?

Tags: microsoft-office, license

Non-subscription versions of Microsoft Office are commercialized with different licenses types:

- FPP (Full Packackaged Product) also known as retail version.
  When PKC or ESD is not mentioned, the FFP version should be assumed, even if not mentionned explicitely. (For the same of simplicity I'm not talking about volume licences here.)
- PKC (Product Key Code)
- ESD (Elecronic Software Distribution)

These license types come with different rights.
To keep it short:

- Only **FFP is transferable** and reinstallable.
- **PCK is not transferable**, but reinstallable.
- ESD is not transferable. (Not sure if reinstallable ; maybe if having written down the licence key.)

Unfortunately, **many online merchants, as not aware of these differences** and the terminology they use leads to **very confusing descriptions** of Microsoft's products.

Example: "Microsoft Office Home and Business 2019, Vollversion, Product Key card".
(Vollversion is the German word for FPP)

Obviously, the confusion comes here from the fact that the full version of Office 2019 comes as a small package with a Product Key Card in it, although it is not the PKC version, the later being sold as a flat card without further packaging.

The fact that Microsoft Office 2010 PKC version was packaged more or less like nowadays FPP version certainly increased the confusion level.

To make things even more confusing, I now see merchants showing the picture of a flat card to illustrate the FFP version, or using the picture of a small box to illustrate the PKC version.

So, **the one and only way for me to know what I'm going to buy would be using the product codes**, like "79G-05412", "T5D-03315", a.s.o.

Unfortunately, on Microsoft's website (nor elsewhere), **I cannot find any official product list or catalogue that would describe which code matches which product**, and how should it be packaged (e.g. small box, card, a.s.o.)

I'm not asking specifically for the two example product codes mentionned above, but I'm looking for a more general product catalogue that would mention the product codes. For both current and past products.

I don't understand why Microsoft makes it so hard for people checking what they are buying.

Sources:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/archive/blogs/uspartner_ts2team/what-are-the-differences-between-office-2010-pkc-fpp-and-vl
- https://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/blog/how-to-transfer-microsoft-office-to-another-computer/#tab2

Comment: It is up to online merchants to market office in an intelligent manner, Microsoft has no control over merchant marketing, nor are they obligated to clear up merchant marketing foolishness by creating conversion tables for product numbers. Your first link makes it clear what you are buying.